# how to draw an interaction diagram

Tags: architecture, uml

I have 10 classes.  I want to diagram out how they interact for my fellow developers.  What diagram type is the best for this?

IE class 1 requests data object a from class 2 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A final answer does not seem to be possible. I recommend to create one (or more) *sequence diagram(s)* depending on the complexity of your use cases. [A nice tutorial is available here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html) (just googled for 'uml sequence diagram').

Edit: Just a reminder. UML can become very complex, so you may not want to document all interactions in detail. Describe the high-level concepts and keep [THIS](http://agilemanifesto.org/iso/en/) in mind.

Comment: I agree.  Just get a whiteboard and go for it.  Depending on your developers / internal culture an informal whiteboard session might be more productive than a formal UML diagram.